# How to get the subtraction result of two EditText in third EditText for Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android programming. While making a program I was looking for the program to auto fill the **subtraction** result of two `EditText` widgets in third `EditText`, without any button. Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: post your code here and let us know if you have any errors..

Comment: I have posted the answer for your scenario, please let me know whether it work for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
int firstvalue=FirstText.getText.Tostring();
int secondvalue=SecondText.getText.Tostring();
int Answer=firstvalue - secondvalue;
thirdvalue.setText(Answer);
```

Hope it works. If any Problem occour tell me

Comment: int firstvalue=Integer.valueOf(FirstText.getText().Tostring());
int secondvalue=Integer.valueOf(SecondText.getText().Tostring());
int Answer=firstvalue - secondvalue;
thirdvalue.setText(String.valueOf(Answer));

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnEditorAction Listener Method to edit Text and do what you want when the focus change

```
editText2.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
 if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
 //do here your stuff f
  int value1=Integer.valueOf(edittext1.getText().Tostring());
  int value2=Integer.valueOf(edittext2.getText().Tostring());
  int value3=value1 - value2;
  thirdvalue.setText(String.valueOf(value3));
 return true;
 }
 return false;
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   EditText  e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   EditText  e2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
   EditText e3=(EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editText3);




e2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
    if(!s.equals("") )
            {
   float a= Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
   float b= Float.parseFloat(e2.getText().toString());
   float c=a-b;
   e3.setText(String.valueOf(c);

           }
    }

}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse I assume You'll do all the error handling. but this code will only if both fields are filled!.

```
Field1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field1);
Field2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field2);
Field3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field3);


Field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0 && Field2.getText().length() != 0)
        Field3.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) - Integer.parseInt(Field2.getText().toString())));
   }
  });

Field2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0 && Field1.getText().length() != 0)
         Field3.setText(""+( Integer.parseInt(Field1.getText().toString()) -  Integer.parseInt(s.toString())));
   }
  });
```